# Get Database Results from a Multiplayer game

Tags: c#, database, sockets, multiplayer

I hope you can help me or at least point me to the direction.
Everything has been programmed in c#, but client applications can be in whatever language, just need to know tcp protocol used for communicating with servers.

I made a server application, which include a lobby and a game server. You can mount as many game server as you need (actually, I have three, just for test, each one with a different kind of game).

The client application connects to lobby for authentication, nd other little things, and request for a game ... after this it's redirected to the appropiate game server.

All the information processed during the game, statistics, chats, ... is saved in a PostgreSQL database (you can configure this for use MySQL, MS SQL).

Now, the players would like to make some queries to get past info about themself, or stats, or whatever ... my question is:

¿Should I keep players query directly the database, I mean obtain the results from the database server (sending the respective sotre procedure command to get the results)?

or (due to they keep an active alive connection with lobby server by socket (and anothers with game server))

¿Do I receive the request and send the results of each query via lobby server using the permanent active connection socket?

¿Which one is the most performance or even secure? or ¿Will you recommend another suggestion?

It's good to say that 5.000 - 10.000 concurrent connections or even more are expected on all game servers.

---

.- I forgot to mention that some queries can has large results, I mean, 500/2000 records (rows) with some columns.
.- Forgot to say that I was thinking to set the queries via socket, processing and packaging the query in the server and sending the result to player(s) zipped (compressed).

Thanks in advance

E/R

Comment: I think there is not such ambiguety ... and for me is a real question ... I just like to know some suggestions that in fact has been given for some nice people ... thanks

Answer (score 2):

You should absolutely not have the players clients directly submitting queries to your database servers; your game servers should have their own protocol for queries that the clients submit, and the 'game query servers' should sanity-check those queries before building the actual SQL.

Under no circumstances should you be building queries directly from user-submitted info, though.

Comment: +1, in addition he should not return 500/2000 records at the same time. What's the use?  It's not likely that the user will browse all. Send paged results.

Answer (score 0):

Most secure is ovbiously the solution where the user does not know the SQL-Server, that is where the lobby server handles all connections and communication (assuming no exploitable bugs on either server ofc). Also you have more control over the implementation of security, having one user (the lobby server), most likely in the same domain, who gets read and execute permissions for exactly only the databases he needs to have those permissions for. Performance < Security, therefore the question regarding performance really does not matter much, but then performance is really also rather a matter of your implementation anyway.